# Why Firebase dynamic link is always null?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a Dynamic link through `createDynamicLink` that is inside the `class DynamicLinkService`, after this I use `retrieveDynamicLink` for the part of reading the link that is opened from the android browser, but it prints that it is null, therefore it does not enter the if and does not push to another route inside the if

```
class DynamicLinkService {
  Future<void> retrieveDynamicLink(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
      final Uri? deepLink = data?.link;
      print("deepLink: $deepLink");

      if (deepLink != null) {
        print("deepLink If: $deepLink");
        String deepLinks = deepLink.toString();
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => linkInvitacionScreen(deepLinks)));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<String> createDynamicLink(String groupID) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://notforget.page.link/',
      link: Uri.parse(
          'https://notforget.com/groupid?$groupID'),
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.example.not_forget_flutter',
        minimumVersion: 1,
      ),
    );

    final ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters);
    final Uri shortUrl = shortDynamicLink.shortUrl;

    print(shortUrl);
    return shortUrl.toString();
  }
}
```

intent filter of AndroidManifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Deep linking -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="notforget.page.link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

i tried various solutions but none led me to get a value in `deeplink`, what am i doing wrong?, thanks.

Comment: Please post the intent filter you added in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I added it there, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Replace Your Host From android:host="notforget.page.link" To android:host="notforget.page.link"

Comment: What's the point in replacing a string with an identical string ??

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).